# Cannot sort objects in thymeleaf using custom comparator

Tags: java, html, spring, sorting, thymeleaf

I am trying to sort objects when user clicks on price or status. What I have so far is this page where I list user tasks the usual way using thymeleaf:

```
<div th:each="task: ${tasks}">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4 th:text="${task.title}"></h4>...
```

[image]

My goal is when user clicks on price or accepted the list to get sorted by price or by status of task. I found out that thymeleaf offers sort method where you can insert your list but also a custom comparator like that:

```
th:each="task: ${#lists.sort(tasks,priceComparator)}"
```

On the controller side I have this:

```
List<Task> userTasks = getUserTasks();

Comparator<Task> priceComparator =  new Comparator<Task>()
    {
      @Override
      public int compare(Task task1, Task task2)
      {
        return task1.getPrice().compareTo(task2.getPrice());
      }
    };
```

And then I set the attributes so I can use them on the front-end:

```
model.addAttribute("priceComparator",priceComparator);
model.addAttribute("tasks",userTasks);
```

I couldn't find anything on the internet about sorting thymeleaf list of objects dynamically using different criterias like price, status and so on (in my case).  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking to sort in the browser, without a round-trip to the server? Thymeleaf only runs on the server, as a pre-processor for your HTML - so it would not help, if that is the case. If you do hit the server, then there are better ways to sort lists (Java code, not Thymeleaf). If you want to stay in the client then my suggestion would be to look at JavaScript-based data grids/tables. (Personally I have never needed `#lists.sort()`).

Comment: @andrewjames Thank you for your answer Andrew, now I got things more clear. Yes I would like to sort only client side and no effect on the back. So I'll look for a way sorting the received list using JavaScript.